# Can an algorithm that yields $O(n^2)$ answers run in $O(n)$ time?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, asymptotics

My question may actually be more broadly described as: can I use the fact that an algorithm is expected to return $(O(f(n))$ answers to show that it may never run better than $O(f(n))$? I would intuitively assume yes, but I am not sure.

Examples of what I'm talking about is algorithms to calculate all the paths that pass through a set of points. I can easily calculate a higher bound $O(f(n))$ on how many those paths are. Will that tell me the algorithm must be no better than $\Omega(f(n))$?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that e.g. $n = O(n!)$, so...

Comment: Technically if you meant $\Theta(n^2)$, then you could give a representation of the $n^2$-sized structure instead of explicitly giving it. For example, if you are given an array of size $n$ to output an $n\times n$ matrix, outputting $[n] * n$ can be valid. But in terms of explicitly giving a solution, then the answer is no, as given by @David.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can an algorithm that yields $O(n^2)$ answers run in $O(n)$ time?

Yes.  The following algorithm yields $O(n^2)$ answers (remember what $O(\cdot)$ means!) but it runs in time $O(n)$.

```
halt;
```

You probably meant to ask if an algorithm that yields $\Theta(n^2)$ answers can run in time $O(n)$. The answer to that is no. Whatever exact definition you choose for "yielding an answer", yielding one answer must take at least one computation step in any reasonable model of computation, so writing $\Theta(n^2)$ answers must take $\Omega(n^2)$ steps.

Comment: What does $O(\cdot)$ mean?

Comment: "Big-O of something." I could have said "remember what $O$ means" but that looks a bit weird because it's always $O(\text{something})$ with the brackets.

Comment: Ah, I thought it may have had some particular meaning I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Nope. But no harm in checking!

Answer (score 4):

If the algorithm (modelled, say by a Turing Machine writing the output on a special output tape) generates at least $f(n)$ output, its running time can't be less than the time required to write it out, i.e., it's $\Omega(f(n))$.

Can't say anything about an upper bound. Think for example about the problem of determining if an array is sorted, the result is clearly just "yes" or "no", while the running time is at least the size of the array, and that isn't $O(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound of an algorithm usually has little bearing on it's lower bound. Take for example the following Bubble Sort algorithm:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n-i;j++){
        if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
            swap(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(!flag) break;
}
```

This algorithm typically has an upper bound of $O(n^2)$. But in case the input is a sorted array, then the flag is never set to 1 in the first pass and we break out only after n comparisons. So this algorithm is $\Omega(n)$,ie it has a lower bound of $O(n)$.

You may want to consider tight bounds on an algorithm. An algorithm that has $\Theta(f(n))$ will have an upper bound of $O(f(n))$ and a lower bound of $\Omega(f(n))$.

Answer (score -3):

In essence, the running time depends on the size of the data and the format in which data is provided to the algorithm.

Otherwise, there seems to be a little correlation between the complexity of algorithm under different set of inputs.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The asker is clearly already aware that the running time depends on the input but is asking about dependence on the output. And I don't understand your second sentence at all.